# Looking for a specific lowercase mathbb font

Tags: fonts, mathbb

I am trying to reproduce this lowercase k with some `mathbb` font

[image]

I have tried using the bbm font, bbold font and mathds  without success. I either get

[image]

that is not what I am looking for.

I was able to reproduce the desired symbol with `\Bbbk` but I read that the package `\Bbb` is out of date and should be avoided.

Comment: the symbol you want, do you have it in a pdf file, or just a scan of paper?

Comment: The command `\Bbb` is deprecated, but `amssymb` provides `\Bbbk` which is the appropriate command for the glyph you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\Bbb` that used to be part of `amsfonts` has been deprecated in favor of `\mathbb`. However, `\Bbbk` is still the command for the blackboard bold lowercase k and is defined in `amssymb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\Bbb{A}$ % deprecated

$\Bbbk$

\end{document}
```

The command `\Bbb{A}` produces a warning

```
Package amsfonts Warning: Obsolete command \Bbb; \mathbb should be used instead
 on input line 6.
```

but the command `\Bbbk` is perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Spectacular. In word there is a font, but I do not remember exactly if you call it math js-bold font that has exactly the glyphs of \mathbb in upper and lower case. I thought it could be called up with the LaTeX. Congratulations again and I extend my sincerest greetings.

Comment: How can I use this to produce other letters? It doesn't seem to work for "r"